# Creation of virtual directory http//localhost failed with the error.File name " file directory".Cannot write configuration file

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

When I open my solution I see this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the users folder is protected. If yes, change the 'ReadOnly' attribute and try again.

If it is corporate environment, there may be chance that your folder may be encrypted. Please turn it off if any.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case "Read Only" won't stay checked. When I check the properties again, it shows filled in.